# How to dynamically add a delivery delay to an outbound message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a JMS outbound gateway which i use to send messages to multiple queues in a queue manager. The destination is determined on the fly using the `destinationExpression` method:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendTo101() {
    return flow -> flow
            .handle(Jms
                    .outboundAdapter(context.getBean("connection101", ConnectionFactory.class))
                    .destinationExpression("headers.destinationName")
                    .configureJmsTemplate(spec -> spec
                            .explicitQosEnabled(true)
                            .get().setDeliveryDelay(180000)
                    )
                    .get(),
                    endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.advice(context.getBean(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.class))
            );

}
```

Now there's a need to set a delivery delay to a certain subset of messages that come in. Is there any way to use the contents of the message to determine if i should add a delay or not?

I could have a filter further up which checks for this property and redirects the flow to another outbound gateway, but that would be quite a bit of redundant code so i wanted to make sure that there wasn't a better way.

Also, different messages require different delays. Is it possible to set a different delay per message? I do realize that the delay property is on the Message Producer and not something you set on the message according to the JMS spec, but i'm fine with making a new JMS producer per message even though it hinders performance.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I can suggest in this case is like to have top level `JmsTemplate` bean and set its `deliveryDelay` in advance of the `Jms.outboundAdapter()`. But in this case all your messages must be processed in this flow in the same `Thread` to avoid concurrent modification.

We have `DynamicJmsTemplate` which is based on the `DynamicJmsTemplateProperties`. And the last one uses `ThreadLocal` to change `priority` and `receiveTimeout` per request.

I'm pretty sure that your request for the `deliveryDelay` can be considered as a part of that feature.

Only the problem here that target `JmsTemplate` doesn't use getter but gets access to the property directly. So, first of all we have to ask Spring Framework team (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) to refactor `JmsTemplate` internal for better inheritance.